# Magento 1 : How to add Home Page in Top Menu?

Tags: url, magento-1.7

The site URL is http://juicecore.com/. I could really use some guidance on getting that top navigation link for “Home” to point to the same CMS home page as the main URL and logo do.

The top menu was created by creating categories and assigning static blocks to them.
The static block assigned to the top nav Home link is coded as

```
<ul><li><a class="level0" href="http://juicecore.com/">Home</a></li></ul>
```

I also tried using “/” and a full path url, no dice.
The logo points to the index page which corresponds to the CMS page assigned for home page content.
`System/Configuration/General/Web/Default Pages/CMS Home Page` is set to use the correct page.
I tried editing this line is topnav.phtml a few different ways, no dice:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
```

After many Google and forum searches, I’m at a loss as to what to try next. I just need that home link to point to the same CMS content page as the logo and main url http://juicecore.com/ do. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you assigned static block to top menu?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Whenever getting URLs**

*Don't use a hardcoded URL.*

In the CMS, use

```
{{store url=''}}
```

In PHP, use

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>
```

**2. Ensure you set the CMS homepage**

In `System > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages`

[image]

Comment: I'll review what's there and make these changes right away. Thank you for the suggestions! :)